# Perform with and without query MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Can i have 2 results within a single query?

For example:
I have the following query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id 
WHERE table1.user_id = $var;
```

I want the first result is `WHERE table1.user_id = $var`.
The second result is loop without `WHERE table1.user_id = $var`.

Comment: A query is designed to produce a result set - you make your query return the result set you want.

Comment: why do you exactly want to do?

Comment: @AdrianCornish if i'm not mistaken (*idk*) the OP wants to have results `table1.user_id = $var` and followed by ` `table1.user_id <> $var`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want the result on which the `userid` is equal to `$var` to be on top of the result on which `userid` is  not equal to `$var`?

```
SELECT * 
FROM   table1 
       JOIN table2 
           ON table1.id = table2.id 
ORDER BY IF(table1.user_id = $var, 0 , 1) ASC
```

Comment: I got it, Thanks
Doens't matter asc or acse